# How can I create manual data from database in multiple choice field without fetching data

Tags: html, forms

There is an area on the site that normally has provincial and district elections.

District names are automatically filled in the multiple-choice field according to the province selection.

It pulls the data from the database. I was also asked to choose a country.

The country should appear as 2 values that I will enter, not from the database.

If one of the defined countries is selected, it is necessary to fetch the data from the database in the other old structure.

But if a different country is selected, it is necessary to enter the same value for the province and district information.

This field is only done on the html page. For other province and district selections, it just connects to the controller and automatically selects it from the database.

.cshtml code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Country:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <dropdown required placeholder="Select Country..." selected="selectedCountry" property="item.Name" method="api/CountryApi/GetCountry">
        </dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Province:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <dropdown required placeholder="Select Province..." selected="selectedProvinceId" property="item.Name" method="api/ProvinceTownApi/GetProvince" name="Id">
        </dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Town:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selectedTown" ng-options="y.Name for y in Town" required>
            <option label="Select Town" value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CountryApiController:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetCountry")]
public IEnumerable<object> GetCountry()
{
    List<string> tempListProvince = new List<string>();

    tempListProvince.Add("USA");
    tempListProvince.Add("England");

    String[] str = tempListProvince.ToArray();

    return tempListProvince;
}
```

I tried to do it this way, but in country selection values, it comes as undefined in 2 values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Comment: In that. It goes to the API in the country selection, takes the error-free values and returns them. But I couldn't show the values on the front, now it shows as undefined. @NicoHaase

Comment: "It shows as undefined" - what does that mean? Can you add more details about this, along with a tag for the programming language you are using?

Comment: It goes to the controller, takes the values, and does not show the values in the html. But this only happens in the country selection. Others come with values from the database. I added country selection. I give the values manually in the controller, but I cannot print the values on the front. It looks like this. Select country:
in multiple choice field: Value1: "undefined", Value2: "undefined" @NicoHaase

Comment: I took a screenshot like this: https://imgur.com/rALwPuq @NicoHaase

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Explain everything you can in text form. Also, share your debugging attempts